# Regex URL javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

About validation URL format:
regex using:

`const regex = /^(?:(?:https?):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]-*)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]-*)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?$/;`

should pass:

`const string1 = 'http://www.example.com'`

`const string2 = 'http://example.com'`

`const string3 = 'www.example.com'`

`const string4 = 'example.com'`

should fail:
`const string5 = 'www.example'`
`const string6 = 'http://www.example'`

but `string5 , string6` still pass, I just newbie regex.

Link reference: https://jsbin.com/hegocoyoge/edit?js,console

Comment: how can your regex become very long?

Comment: That's quite a complicated regular expression, can you explain what exactly you're trying to do with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: For checking url this long regex ?

Comment: Validating URLs can be done with `URL` constructor

Comment: I found this solution on stack then sorry I oso dont understand clearly this regex, but I wanna check 1 more option is `www.example` or `http://www.example` will fail -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use this simple compact regex, instead of your so big unmaintainable regex? Which seems to satisfy your exact requirements mentioned in your post's samples.

```
^(http:\/\/)?(www\.)?\w+\.\w{1,3}$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q2BpPS/1)**

Comment: Thank so much sir, it really what I want ^^

Comment: @XuânBình: If my solution worked for you, can you please upvote/accept my answer? Thanks :)

Comment: oh yes, you need 15+ rep for voting privilege I guess. Keep asking good questions and give good answers so you keep getting more rep and privileges :)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems very complex. It doesn't have to be.. 
Try this:

```
var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
var regex = new RegExp(expression);
var t = 'www.google.com';
if (t.match(regex)) {
  console.log("This is a valid url");
} else {
  console.log("This is not a valid url");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support sir

Answer (score -1):

I'll highly recommend use some library. For example [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator). Authors already solved these problems. If you still want to implement your own (unreadable) regEx try to look to source of some `isEmail` library like:
https://github.com/chriso/validator.js/blob/master/src/lib/isEmail.js

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'm using it in my project, but not enough for validate. So i need combine with regex for make sure validation is correct